# destroyed the session and userdata but still shows shows the content after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am in delima that i had distroyed the session and userdata when i click on logout button and it redirects to the login page. It works perfectly but i discovered the problem when i click on back button on browser and its show the page from which i had logout which shouldn't be displayed but redirects the homepage is not it ? I am really in trouble.

```
public function logout(){
     $this->session->unset_userdata('user_email');
     $this->session->unset_userdata('user_type');    

     $this->session->sess_destroy();


        redirect(site_url(),'refresh');
}
```

Now i had also set the redirect on constructor in controller of that page where i had set the logout button.

```
public function __construct() {



    parent::__construct();

     if(!$this->session->userdata('user_type')|| !$this->session->userdata('user_email')){
         redirect(site_url(),"refresh"); 
     }



    $this->load->model('health_model');
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try putting `unset($this->session->userdata); ` or `$this->session->userdata = array();` after `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Check what `sess_destroy()` is doing. Logically it just destroys (given the name), as such wont delete the user data you are trying to get rid of, as per:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset.

Also here:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

It states:

> unset_userdata() can be used to remove data from the session, by
>   passing the session key. For example, if you wanted to remove
>   'some_name' from your session information:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');

This function can also be passed an associative array of items to unset.

$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

Just make sure you are unsetting the required data, namely whatever Codeigniter uses to determine if a user is logged in.
At the moment you are just unsetting `user_email` and `user_type`, so try something like `user_id`.